# android How to open last activity when tapping notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have observed several similar questions but they couldn`t help me. I need to display last activity when user click notification. Here is my code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(YourService.this)
        .setContentTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(getServiceStateDescription(YourService.this))
        .setSmallIcon(iconId)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

Intent nIntent = getPreviousIntent();
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity_.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(nIntent);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

startForeground(ContextConstants.LAUNCHER_SERVICE_NOTE_ID, notificationBuilder.build());


private Intent getPreviousIntent() {
Intent newIntent = null;
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    final List<ActivityManager.AppTask> recentTaskInfos = activityManager.getAppTasks();
    if (!recentTaskInfos.isEmpty()) {
        for (ActivityManager.AppTask appTaskTaskInfo: recentTaskInfos) {
            if (appTaskTaskInfo.getTaskInfo().baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName().equals(ContextConstants.PACKAGE_NAME)) {
                newIntent = appTaskTaskInfo.getTaskInfo().baseIntent;
                newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    final List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTaskInfos = activityManager.getRecentTasks(1024, 0);
    if (!recentTaskInfos.isEmpty()) {
        for (ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo recentTaskInfo: recentTaskInfos) {
            if (recentTaskInfo.baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName().equals(ContextConstants.PACKAGE_NAME)) {
                newIntent = recentTaskInfo.baseIntent;
                newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }
        }
    }
}
if (newIntent == null) newIntent = new Intent();
return newIntent;
```

}

Second point is that if i used deprecated metods in order to build notification, displaying last activity works great as i wanted here is code:

```
Notification note = new Notification(iconId,
            getResources().getText(R.string.serviceStarted),
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    Intent nIntent = new Intent();
    nIntent = getPreviousIntent(nIntent);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, nIntent, 0);
    note.setLatestEventInfo(this,
            getResources().getText(R.string.app_name), getServiceStateDescription(YourService.this), pi);

    startForeground(ContextConstants.LAUNCHER_SERVICE_NOTE_ID, note);
```

`But i don't want use deprecated metods anymore, that's why i'm here explaining. Thanks in advance!`

And i've seen [this](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html) doc as well.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <activity android:name=".activity.StartingActivity_"  android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity_"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ComposeEmailActivity_"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity_">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.MainActivity_" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.EditAccountActivity_"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity_">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.MainActivity_" />
    </activity>               

    <!--android:process=":remote" is for working in background-->
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".service.YourService"/>       

</application>
```

Comment: Do you just want to bring your application to the foreground in whatever state it was in when it went to the background?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the methods you are using to build the `Notification`. Your problem is your use of `TaskStackBuilder`. Using this class performs a lot of hidden magic behind the scenes and it makes a lot of assumptions about how your want the app to behave. Unfortunately, these assumptions are mostly wrong :-(

If you just want to bring your application to the foreground in whatever state it was in when it went to the background, you don't want to use `TaskStakBuilder` and you also don't have to use all those nasty `ActivityManager` methods. Just do this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(YourService.this)
    .setContentTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.app_name))
    .setContentText(getServiceStateDescription(YourService.this))
    .setSmallIcon(iconId)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

Intent nIntent = getPackageManager().
        getLaunchIntentForPackage(ContextConstants.PACKAGE_NAME);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, nIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

startForeground(ContextConstants.LAUNCHER_SERVICE_NOTE_ID,
    notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you _@David Wasser_ for quickly reply, but it opens launcher activity always.

Comment: Also, how are you starting the app for the first time? From the installer or from an IDE or by clicking on the app icon from the HOME screen?

Comment: I have launched debug apk from android studio.

Comment: Launcher activity  is StartingActivity_ on me, that`s why always it opens by tapping notification.

Comment: There is a nasty Android bug that you are probably seeing. Please try the following: Do not launch your App from Android Studio. Just deploy the app on the phone (or emulator) and then start it manually by tapping the app icon from the HOME screen. Then see if your notification always opens the launcher Activity.

Comment: Glad to help. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265 for more details about the bug.

Comment: How can we resume existing application?
by above code it launch every time new application even application is in background.

Comment: @ScottyB please don't suggest using `singleTask` launch mode! This is not the correct solution. It creates a lot more problems than it solves. Standard Android behaviour, when calling `startActivity()` with a "launch Intent" retrieved from the `PackageManager` , is to bring the existing task to the foreground **without creating a new instance of the `Activity`**. If you are seeing multiple instances of the `Activity` there is something else wrong. Special launch modes should hardly ever be used (unless you are building a HOME-screen replacement)

Comment: Thanks @DavidWasser. I didn't realize that. (I deleted my comment) I had just read a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163367/resume-an-activity-when-clicked-on-a-notification and saw a similar answer!

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツdid you find a solution?